# Deploy SSRS to google sites

Tags: reporting-services, google-sites, ssrs-2014

I wonder if any one can explain how to deploy a report server project to google sites? If a understand it right I need a report server for publishing the reports.

Comment: Doubt it - who told you that?

Comment: I need to install a report server for publishing right?

Comment: Hi @Nörden, google vs microsoft or 2 arch-enemies in term of tech ...

Comment: I am not clear o your requirement. Report server comes free with sql server and is MS sql server specific. To the best of my knowledge you cannot publish an SSRS project to any other product since reports are stored in SQL server. If you are delivering reports inside your company then you should publish to report server local to your company.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/12864810-provide-a-way-to-deploy-native-ssrs-to-a-web-app

Comment: @P.Salmon So you mean we can not show the created reports on our google site?

Comment: I vote to close this question. OP has not done any homework and is not showing any problem related to programming that we need to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy a SQL Server Reporting Services project to Google Sites as running the reports requires... SQL Server Reporting Services, which is a part of the SQL Server ecosystem and not availabel on Google Sites.

You could perhaps run the report in SSRS and then export the output as HTML to the Google Sites project so you have a snapshot but you will not be able to run it in realtime. You may also be able to run it on a schedule to export the HTML version and have a process that auto uploads it via FTP.